# Autoplay in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, html5-audio, e2e-testing

I need to e2e test sound autoPlay. Is that possible to setup puppeteer in the way it allows autoPlay?

I understand that sound will not be played, but HTMLAudioElement acts like playing if I clickbon the play button, I need the same thing but with autoPlay

Answer (score 4):

You will need to launch chrome with [`--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#no-user-gesture-required) launch flag.

> Autoplay policy that does not require any user gesture.

It applies both for video and audio sources.

E.g.

```js
await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: ['--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required'] })
```